# Can't deploy CDC on PricebookentryChangeEvent

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, change-data-capture

I made a Trigger on PricebookEntryChangeEvent and added Pricebook Entry to the CDC Selected Entity list.

I've also added PlatformEventChannelMember with a wildcard in the Package.xml. ThePricebookEntryChangeEvent was in the Changes in VS Code. but when I try to deploy to another sandbox I get this Error:
[image: Deploy Error]

The change vscode detected was this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlatformEventChannelMember xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <eventChannel>ChangeEvents</eventChannel>
    <selectedEntity>PricebookEntryChangeEvent</selectedEntity>
</PlatformEventChannelMember>
```

Did I forget to push something or is it just not possible to deploy CDC?